# preventDefault() stops a tag from working

Tags: html, jquery, href

I'm trying to make my navbar links use the active class, so i can switch styles on click.
But when i put preventDefault() in my onclick event to stop the event to refresh the page, it stops working completely, the links won't work at all

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-style ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/">Acasa</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/about us">About us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/apartments">Apartments</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/houses">Houses</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/location">Location</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

and the jquery that i use:

```
$(".navbar-nav .nav-link").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".navbar-nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
```

Comment: So why are you adding preventDefault()? I think your idea here is flawed, if you change the classes on an element and then reload the page, you are going to lose those changes anyways.

Comment: That's what `preventDefault()` does. If you're expecting the class you add on page A to still be shown on page B, that's not going to work. You need to add the class *after* the browser has moved to page B

Comment: well yes thats the thing, with preventdefault my url doesn't even change anymore it stays at '/'

Comment: Remove the handler. Instead, add `$(function () { $(".navbar-nav").find(\`.nav-link[href$="${location.href.slice(location.href.lastIndexOf('/'))}"]\`).addClass("active")`.

Comment: yes, i was wrong, so how should i keep the active class on the linked clicked after the url loads?

Comment: @HereticMonkey, i used your approach but it only works for the first 2 links, it doesnt affect the other ones

Comment: It should, unless you have some redirect going on and the URL does not end with the given text (i.e., when you click on "Location", does the URL end with `/location`?). You might need to change it to `location.pathname` instead of `location.href` if your site uses query strings or something. Anyway, it was just a guess, since your question was about `preventDefault`, not changing the active class.

Comment: I actually work with django and i have 2 urls that end with '/' but the other dont

Comment: And i can't remove the end slashes from those 2 because it return page not found, i don't know how to pass through that.

Comment: Is there an alternative to lastIndexOf ?